# Definition of prefixes of a string

Tags: formal-languages

From Wikipedia:

> The prefixes of a string is the set of all prefixes to a string, with respect to a given language:
>   $$
>     \operatorname{Pref}_L(s) = \{t \mid s=tu \mbox { for } t,u\in \operatorname{Alph}(L)^*\}
> $$
>   here $s\in L$.

So is it equivalent to 
$$
    \operatorname{Pref}_L(s) = \{t \mid t \mbox { is the first $n$ part of $s$}, \forall n \in \{1, \dots, \mbox { length}(s)\} \}?
$$

Answer (score 1):

No.  As you have defined it, $t$ is only in the language if it is every prefix, except $\varepsilon$, of $s$.  That definition describes $\emptyset$ if $|s|$ is not 1, or $\{s\}$ if $s$ is a single symbol.  If you change ∀n∈{1,…, length(s)},  to $\text{s.t.}$ $1 \leq n \leq |s|$, then it would be almost equivalent.  However the first language includes the empty string.

Also "first n part of" is not a very good way to describe a prefix of length n.  It could be ambiguous.  And you should define what $t$ is, i.e. $t \in \Sigma^*$.

Comment: Thanks. (1) What is the differnce between  ∀n∈{1,…, length(s)}, and 1≤n≤|s|? (2)would replacing ∀n∈{1,…, length(s)} with 0≤n≤|s| in my definition, make it the same as the WIkipedia definition?

Comment: (1) You could also say for some $n \in \{1, ..., |s|\}$  instead of $1 \leq n \leq |s|$  The difference between $\forall$ and for some is that for the former, the condition must evaluate to true for all $n \in {1, ..., |s|}$ and the latter must only evaluate to true for at least one $n \in {1, ..., |s|}$  So in the case of for all, a given string t will only be granted membership if it is every prefix of s, except the empty string.  (2) Not exactly.  $Alphabet(L)^*$, usually written as $\Sigma^*$, includes the empty string, $\varepsilon$.

Comment: You could instead say $0\leq n \leq |s|$, but I'm not sure that it makes complete sense to describe the set of strings which are in the first 0 part of a string as the set containing just the empty string.